# Add Javascript to ModalDialog window

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to add JS to modal dialog window that appears after adding document to Document Library. That script will populate a field with value.
E.g. after document added modal window appears with sugested item Title.
Any ideas on how it could be achieved?

PS I know about JSLink and custom fields

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to add script link to JSLink property of Web Part on Edit document form manually.